# "fifth day" + correct tenses of "clean"

Tags: tense

I have made up the examples below.

(1) Today is the fifth day **I'm cleaning** the streets. (I’m cleaning as I speak.)

(2) Today is the fifth day **I've cleaned** the streets. (said as I wrap up the day of cleaning)

(3) Today is the fifth day **I'll clean** the streets. (said before I start my cleaning).

Are these chosen tenses of "clean" correct for different times of the sentences said?

Comment: 1. & 2. YES 3. "... I'm going to clean ...". Comment if you'd like more explanation about why

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to use Today in the first of these sentences as you are already relating to the number of days. It is not incorrect but it is not normal. The streets, which streets? you do not tells us. Therefore the use of streets is not really correct.

1. Your tense is incorrect, you cannot use the present tense **I'm** in this case. (see below)

> It's the fifth day **I've** been cleaning these streets. (I’m cleaning as I speak.)

This shows a continuous amount of days you have been street cleaning as apposed to the sentence below. Yes it is the present when you are speaking but it relates to a time from the past that extends into the present. Finally as you are on the street at this time you could use "*these streets*" as the place is defined by your location.

> **I've** been cleaning streets for five days this week! (I’m cleaning as I speak.)

---

2. 

> **I've** cleaned *the streets* of our neighbourhood for 5 days (said as I wrap up the day of cleaning)

> **I've** cleaned streets for 5 days or **I've** just finished cleaning streets for the fifth day.

---

3. You cannot say I'll (I will) in this case because the action has already started, therefore it will not happen in the future.

> Today is my fifth day of street cleaning.(said before I start my cleaning)

---

**Usage of “Have Been & Has Been”**
‘Has been’ and ‘have been’  suggest an action that started in the past, but continues in the present. Ref [Learn English](https://www.learnenglishteam.com/how-to-use-have-has-had-been/)

When we are talking about the present:

If the subject of a sentence is I – You – We – They or a plural noun (cars, birds, children) we use ‘have been‘.